# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint2

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_JOB_POSTING_CLIENT". The conflict occurred in database "ResLand", table "dbo.CLIENT", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.

i got above exception message while i am inserting the data in job posting screen
 my database design for job_posting table is:

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[JOB_POSTING]
       ([COMP_ID]
       ,[RES_ID]
       ,[RES_TYPE]
       ,[CONTACT_NAME]
       ,[CONTACT_INFO]
       ,[TITLE]
       ,[DESCR]
       ,[PREREQUISITES]
       ,[SKILLS]
       ,[JOB_TYPE]
       ,[LOCATION]
       ,[DURATION]
       ,[POST_DT]
       ,[POST_END_DT]
       ,[POSITIONS_CNT]
       ,[CLIENT_ID]
       ,[CATEGORY]
       ,[RATE]
       ,[PERKS]
       ,[STAT]
       ,[IS_DELETED]
       ,[CR_BY]
       ,[DT_CR]
       ,[MOD_BY]
       ,[DT_MOD])
```

in my controller i wrote the code like this  :

```
    [ValidateInput(false)] 
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostJob(PostJobModel model, string btn)
    {

        if (btn == "Save")
        {

            JOB_POSTING jobPost = new JOB_POSTING();

            jobPost.RES_ID = RL_Constants.RES_ID;
            jobPost.RES_TYPE = RL_Constants.RES_TYPE;
            jobPost.COMP_ID = RL_Constants.COMP_ID;
            jobPost.POST_DT = Convert.ToDateTime(model.POST_DT);
            jobPost.POST_END_DT = Convert.ToDateTime(model.POST_END_DT);
            jobPost.POSITIONS_CNT = Convert.ToInt32(model.POSITIONS_CNTS);
            jobPost.JOB_TYPE =Convert.ToString(model.JOB_TYPE);
            jobPost.DURATION = model.DURATION;
            jobPost.CATEGORY = Convert.ToString(model.CATEGORY_ID);
            jobPost.PREREQUISITES = model.PREREQUISITES;
            jobPost.LOCATION = model.LOCATION;
            jobPost.RATE = model.RATE;
            //CLIENT=model.CLIENT_ID
            //CLIENT_ID=(model.CLIENT_ID)
            jobPost.TITLE = model.POST_TITLE;
            jobPost.DESCR = Regex.Replace(model.DESCRIPTION, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", ""); 
            jobPost.CONTACT_NAME = model.CONTACT_PERSON;
            jobPost.CONTACT_INFO = model.CONTACT_PHONE + "/" + model.CONTACT_EMAIL;
            jobPost.SKILLS = model.SKILLS;
            jobPost.PERKS = model.PERKS;
            jobPost.DT_CR = DateTime.Now;
            jobPost.CR_BY = RL_Constants.USER_NAME;
            jobPost.STAT = "ACTIVE";
            jobPost.IS_DELETED = "N";

            reslandentity.JOB_POSTING.Add(jobPost);
            reslandentity.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("JobSearchList", "Employer");
    }
```

where is the problem

Comment: make sure your model sync with database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that the client Id you're using doesn't exist in the Client table. Are you setting the cliendId fk reference correctly? In the code you've posted the setting of clientId has been commented out. This means that the clientId = 0 (if it's an int), and I bet you don't have any clients with id = 0.

---- Update -----
As your clientId = 0 it tries to make a fk relationship to the client table, which fails. You said you didn't want to use the clientId at this point and that the clientId column was nullable. I'm not sure why it's assigned the 0 value, but just to check that it's working you should do a clientId = null in your mapping. This should prevent EF from trying to make a fk relationship.

Comment: but im not using clientid in this aspect and in database also i truned clientid as allow null

Comment: I made the assumption that your table had a fk relationship to the client table on the ID column. To help you out I'll need more information on your db setup. Are you using EF? Is there a fk relationship between job_posting and client?

Comment: yes  we are using EF, we had fk relation between job_posting clientid and client id but im not using client

Comment: It sounds like you have some issues in your configuration of the tables fk relationships. Please post your config code and I might be able to help you.    Also, please check if jobPost.ClientId has a value when you add it to the repository.

Comment: we dont use jobpost.clientid here

Comment: I know you don't use it. But it's a property on the object, right? please check this property... Is it null or 0?

Comment: it is taking as 0      ---      thanks Zaphod regards sumanth

Comment: if we remove the  foreign key relation  of clietid it working Zaphod

Comment: Great. Then you just need to figure out why the clientId gets set to 0 and remove it.   Please mark as answered if this sorted the issue.